# openstack server live migration progress stuck repeat random but not complete in large memory instance

Tags: memory, openstack, live, migrate, openstack-nova

Openstack **Train** version live migrate instance by:

```
openstack server migrate --wait --live-migration --os-compute-api-version 2.30 --host "$dest_node" "$inst_id"
```

When the instance less used memory(total 64G, used 2G) it works but not with the large used memory(total 64G, used 40G).

Snippet of stuck logs about the large used memory instance:

```
...Migration running for 90 secs, memory 3% remaining(...)
...Migration running for 90 secs, memory 4% remaining(...)
...Migration running for 90 secs, memory 1% remaining(...)
...Migration running for 90 secs, memory 2% remaining(...)
...Migration running for 90 secs, memory 1% remaining(...)...
```

**source node**: **node-36**

**destination node**: **node-35**

Work fine:
[image]
[image]

Stuck in not complete:
[image]
[image]

Comment: On the second one, which stucks in migrating, is there a very high load with much write access on the RAM on the VM? because live-migration also means, that the RAM has to be synchronized between the two nodes before it switch to the other node. Maybe the load on the RAM of the VM is soo high, that libvirt can not reach a synced state.

Comment: @Tobias It stucks in random progress like the last picture, but not to 100 complete. The VM use memory is high, and the TCP connection over 100, is this effect? When or how situation will the libvirt would reach a synced state? And it will finish the live migration? And why the network traffic always in so high value? THX.

Comment: Libvirt tries to sync the memory live and mirror all changes in the RAM to the other node. So if the content of RAM of the source-VM is changed by the programs within the VM faster, then libvirt can sync it over the Network, it fill never finish. If synced memory is overwritten again, the progress goes back. For example, if only the last 40% of the RAM are permanentally extremly fast rewritten, the migration will stuck around 60% of completion. Theoretically libirt/qemu should slow down the VM to support reaching a synced state, but I don't know, if this needs a special configuration.

Comment: Possible help: https://docs.openstack.org/nova/latest/admin/live-migration-usage.html#what-to-do-when-the-migration-times-out.

Comment: THX, I will try.